# Cannot display data from the API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some Graphs (made with Graph js) and I want to display the data in them.

It seems i can fetch them and the data displays in an  made but I cannot display them in the actual graph. I've tried different methods and to even to map it straight in the return field but it still did not work and showed it is undefined.

```
const API = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/models/';
const DEFAULT_QUERY = 'Vno';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            chartData: {},
            hits: [],
            isLoading: false,
            error: null
        };
    }

    getChartData() {
        const hits = this.state;
        const nextMonths = ['February', 'March', 'April', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October'];

        this.setState({
            chartData: {
                labels: hits.pha,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: 'Dataset',
                        fill: false,
                        lineTension: 0.1,
                        backgroundColor: ['rgba(243, 129, 129, 0.4)', 'rgba(75,192,192,0.4)',
                            'rgba(249, 237, 105, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(184, 59, 94, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(106, 44, 112, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(0, 184, 169, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(135, 133, 162, 0.4)'],
                        borderColor: '#fae3d9',
                        borderCapStyle: 'butt',
                        borderDash: [],
                        borderDashOffset: 0.0,
                        borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
                        pointBorderColor: '#212121)',
                        pointBackgroundColor: '#252a34',
                        pointBorderWidth: 3,
                        pointHoverRadius: 5,
                        pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
                        pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
                        pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
                        pointRadius: 5,
                        pointHitRadius: 10,
                        data: [50, 30, 40, 60]
                    }
                ],
            }
        })
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true });
        fetch(API + DEFAULT_QUERY)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    return response.json();
                } else {
                    throw new Error('Something went wrong ...');
                }
            })
            .then(data => this.setState({ hits: data.hits, isLoading: false }))
            .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.getChartData();
    }

    render() {
        const { hits, isLoading, error } = this.state;
        if (error) {
            return <p>{error.message}</p>;
        }

        if (isLoading) {
            return <div className="react-spinner">
                <MDSpinner size={100} />
            </div>
        }
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <Navbar bg="light" variant="light">
                    <Navbar.Brand href="#">Aeroconseil</Navbar.Brand>
                    <Nav className="mr-auto">
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar>
                <hr className="hr-line"></hr>
                <div className="container">
                    <Chart chartData={this.state.chartData} />
                    <LineGraph chartData={this.state.chartData} />
                    <ul>
                        {hits.map(hit =>
                            <li key={hit.name}>
                                <a>{hit.pha}</a>
                            </li>
                        )}
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

I expected the data from the API to be displayed but it says undefined.

Comment: I'm not sure I've seen APIs that return functions. What I mean is, `response.json()` may be the culprit

Comment: It seems is not from the response.json() and it returns a promise so I do not think this is the problem.

Comment: Try const {hits} = this.state instead of const hits = this.state as you are trying to access a property in an object.

Comment: Ok, it still says it's empty but the idea is in render() after logging it it shows the data but in the getChartData() component for the same object it shows it is empty.

Comment: I get it. Its because you are calling the method in componentWillMount which is basically the constructor. You make the API call in componentDidMount which is the next life cycle. So call in your method in componentDidMount after you get the API response and report back if it still doesnt show you the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it. I don't think is a pretty fix but if someone has some ideas or has a similar problem like mine.
(I did not need to call hits on getChartData() or call it on render() const.)

```
let hit_labels = []
      let hit_values = []

      for(let item in this.state.hits){
        hit_labels.push(this.state.hits[item].name);
        let value = parseInt(this.state.hits[item].pha);

        hit_values.push(isNaN(value) ? 0 : value);
      }

      this.state.chartData.labels = hit_labels;
      this.state.chartData.datasets[0].data = hit_values;
      console.log(this.state.chartData);
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things that might be problematic:

1. in the first line of the definition of `getCharData` you should use destructuring, so it should be

```
getCharData() {
  const { hits } = this.state;
  // ...
}
```

2. the lifecycle method `componentWillMount` was [deprecated](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1575) in React 16.3 and was replaced with `UNSAFE_componentWillMount` and maybe that's why you get `undefined`
3. in React [State Updates May Be Asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous), so you could try using the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method instead

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  this.getCharData();
}
```